# how to grant user to access only bucket the user created? aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

is there a possibility for one iam user to be able to create bucket and only have full access to the bucket the user creates and NOT other buckets?

Comment: Does the bucket already exist (do you know its name?), or do you need the user to be able to create a randomly-named bucket and then be restricted to that bucket?

Comment: @jarmod create randomly-named and then restricted to it or any other randomly-named this user creates.

Comment: You might want to consider user-level folders within an existing, shared bucket. For example see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/.

Comment: @Tsuna AWS doesn't track which *user* created a bucket (except during initial bucket creation -- after that, the information is not preserved).  It only matters which *AWS account* created (and thus owns) the bucket.

Comment: @jarmod I do know about using iam and giving permission to an existing bucket that's why I am only asking for NONE existing.  Just a curious question since I couldn't google any results.  Also, thanks for the alternative info provided though

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so I guess that means a big no right?  Just a curious question popped out of no where and I couldn't seem to get anything from googling

Comment: Another option to investigate (I have not tested this) is to use an IAM policy that allows S3 actions against "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}-*" where your IAM users would be restricted to bucket names beginning with their IAM user names. It wouldn't allow random bucket names but it's arguably a good practice anyhow to be able to quickly determine who owns a given bucket in a shared account.

Comment: @Tsuna essentially, that's correct.

Comment: @jarmod thx thx, I believe I get the idea you mentioned. a way to check the bucket if the bucket has at least a prefix of the username or something.  Nice work around, theoretically that should work :D

Comment: If this works for you, just make sure that you indicate <username><hyphen><star> rather than <username><star> otherwise an IAM user named mo will be able to access monica's buckets.